# ¿Como hacer un cast de un struct a un void* y viceversa en C?

Tags: c

Buenas, estoy realizando un programa que lee un archivo Bytecode de Python y ejecuta las instrucciones dadas en el mismo. El problema que tengo en estos momentos es que necesito meter a una pila una estructura de tipo Etiqueta. La pila admite unicamente el tipo void* debido a que allí se puede almacenar cualquier cosa como int, float... 
¿Cuál es la manera correcta para castear un struct a un void* y viceversa?

```
void LOAD_GLOBAL(char * nombreEtiqueta){
    struct Etiqueta *temporal = buscarEtiqueta(nombreEtiqueta);
    insertarElementoPila((void*) &temporal, 6);
}

struct Etiqueta *CALL_FUNCTION(int numParams){
    struct Etiqueta *P = (struct Etiqueta*) pPila;
    return P;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te está dando tu código?

Comment: No necesitas pasar la dirección de `temporal`, ya es un puntero hacia otra cosa.

Comment: @NaCl creo que deberías ponerlo como respuesta ya que esa parte del código es obvio que está mal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Como hacer un cast de un struct a un void* y viceversa en C?

No hace falta una conversión explícita ya que `void *` puede apuntar a cualquier tipo de dato, tienes un ejemplo en las funciones de comparación (callbacks) utilizadas con `qsort`:

```
int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const struct profile *elem1 = p1;    
    const struct profile *elem2 = p2;

    if (elem1->soc < elem2->soc)
        return -1;
    else if (elem1->soc > elem2->soc)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Otra cosa es cuando queremos acceder a su valor (dereferenciarlo) sin usar un puntero intermedio:

```
void fn(void *p)
{
    int x = *(int *)p;

    printf("%d\n", x);
}

int a = 5;
fn(&a);
```

En este caso si hemos tenido que hacer un cast explícito a `int *` ya que no se puede dereferenciar un puntero a `void *` directamente (además de la alineación necesitamos saber el tamaño del tipo pasado y `void *` no nos da ninguna pista acerca de ese tamaño, es el cast quien se lo indica al compilador)